# Как изменить часть текста?

Tags: java, android

Есть текст, загруженный из файла "text_inp". Нахожу в нем строку со словом "word" и читаю от конца слова до конца строки:

```
String str_pattern;
String str_find="word";
Pattern pattern;
Matcher m;
String text_inp = ls.read(PATH_SET,SET);
str_pattern = "(?m)^"+str_find+"(.*)";
pattern = Pattern.compile(str_pattern);
m = pattern.matcher(text_inp);
if (m.find()) {
  Log.d(LOG_TAG,m.group(1))
    }
```

Если найдено, надо найденную строку (m.group(1)) заменить например на "new words" чтобы текст "text_inp" был готов для сохранения.

Comment: Используйте replace или replaceAll.

Comment: Благодарю! Все получилось.